# Powershell "Invoke-Expression or eval" a bash script for sharing/setting environment variables

Tags: bash, powershell, environment-variables, zsh

I have been trying to live with Powershell for a few months as the only scripting environment. I use bash/zsh on Linux and MacOS and CMD on Windows.

The problem I am trying to tackle is where current scripts set environment variables.

In particular, I am trying to have some interoperability between the scripting shells by coming up with a Powershell equivalent to this typical bash/zsh command pattern:

```
$ eval $(./set-my-environment-variables.sh)
```

Is there a way?

Comment: Do you want the setting to be permanent, or to be maintained for only the current PS session?

Comment: Please show sample output from `./set-my-environment-variables.sh`

Comment: I wouldn't say that this pattern is _typical_. I would rather call it unusual, if not dangerous. The normal way to do it would be in both bash and zsh  `.  set-my-environment-variables.sh` or `source  set-my-environment-variables.sh`.